# Selected text showing oversized selection area

Tags: html, css

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this but when I select or highlight text on my page, the selection area is too big. I've found this to cause issues with anchor points within the text.

As you can see from the photo below, I have only selected the words "What is "APR"?" but the area is showing above it too.

[image]

I have checked my css and can't see anything that could cause this, any ideas?

UPDATED

CSS

```
h3 {    
    color: rgb(0, 156, 222);
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25.3px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Due to the sensitive nature of the site I can't post any code. I was hoping someone might be able to throw some ideas to try out and if something works then great. If it helps, it only does this on `<h3></h3>` tags. I'll add the css to the question.

Comment: A. you can post only "Loerm Ispum" content as `html` and `css` in your fiddle only. B. My guess is that it's related to `float` or `line-height` of one of the `h3` parents.

Comment: adding a `clear` before `<h3>` may solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. So I have the `<a name="anchor"></a>` within my `<h3></h3>` and it's causing this issue. If I put the anchor tag outside the `<h3>` it's fine.